# gevent-compatible reentrant lock?

Tags: python, locking, gevent

What is the [RLock](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.RLock) equivalent in gevent? If there is no equivalent, how to identify the current greenlet so I can implement one?

From reading the source, [gevent.lock.BoundedSemaphore(1)](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.lock.html#gevent.lock.BoundedSemaphore) is the equivalent of a simple (non-reentrant) Lock. Testing also indicates this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `gevent.lock` module has an implementation of `RLock` which uses the `getcurrent` method of `gevent.hub` to identify the current greenlet.  Here is a simple example.

```
from gevent.lock import RLock

lock = RLock()
with lock:
     print("acquired once")
     with lock:
          print("acquired twice")
```

While I didn't find any documentation [here](http://www.gevent.org/gevent.lock.html), you can always read the [source](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/master/src/gevent/lock.py#L203).

Comment: It never occurred me to browse the source. The documentation doesn't mention `RLock` at all, which is why I gave up there. ty.